# How to change Quarkus context path at startup

Tags: quarkus, vert.x

For a cloud native application written with Vert.x, I need to change the context path using an environment variable depending on where it is deployed. I tried with:

```
quarkus.http.root-path=${CONTEXT_PATH:/app}
```

in `application.properties` but it is not taken into account at runtime, just at build time. [Here](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.root-path) is also reported that this property is build time only. What's the way to change the context path then?

Comment: "*Is this the correct behavior?*" - [It is as documented](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.root-path). Without looking it up, I imagine there is a good reason why it is a build-time property. --- "*What's the way to change the context path then?*" - I'd assume that we have to [re-augment](https://quarkus.io/guides/reaugmentation) the application.

Comment: It seems a bit overcomplicated. It's very strange there's no other easier way.

Comment: It is a build-time property. It wasn't meant to be overridden easily. Keep in mind that build-time properties a) contribute to the fast startup-time and b) play a major role in native compilation.